# Cannot load a plugin to frama-c with call to ocamlyices functions

Tags: frama-c

I am trying to develop a plugin to frama-c. 
I did build the application, which has several files, and then created the `makefile` referencing all the files i needed.

I am able to use `make` and then `make install` and execute the plugin. My problem appears when i call functions from the `ocamlyices` library in a function...

I am still able to do the make and make install and when i try to execute i get the following error:

```
[kernel] warning: cannot load plug-in 'name' (incompatible with Fluorine-20130601).

[kernel] user error: option `<name>' is unknown.
use `frama-c -help' for more information.

[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

So it says it is incompatible when I add the call to `ocamlyices` functions. Is there any option/configuration I am missing somewhere?

Thank you for your help.

The final solution looked like this:

```
FRAMAC_SHARE := $(shell frama-c.byte -print-path)
FRAMAC_LIBDIR := $(shell frama-c.byte -print-libpath)
PLUGIN_NAME = Fact

# All needed files
PLUGIN_CMO = ../base/basic_types concolic_search run_fact ../lib/lib 

PLUGIN_DOCFLAGS = -I ../base -I ../lib -I $(YICES) -I /usr/lib/ocaml/batteries -I ../instrumentation
PLUGIN_BFLAGS = -I ../base -I ../lib -I $(YICES) -I ../instrumentation 
PLUGIN_OFLAGS = -I ../base -I ../lib -I $(YICES) -I ../instrumentation 

PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE = $(YICES)/ocamlyices.cma 
PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT = $(YICES)/ocamlyices.cmxa

include $(FRAMAC_SHARE)/Makefile.dynamic
```

The variable $(YICES) is defined as

```
export YICES="/usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.12.1/ocamlyices"
```

Comment: Did you add: -I +ocamlyices to the PLUGIN_BFLAGS and PLUGIN_OFLAGS Makefile variables, ocamlyices.cma to PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE and ocamlyices.cmxa to PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Anne, if your plug-in uses an external library that is not already included by Frama-C itself, you need a few more steps than for a basic plug-in, especially setting `PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE` and `PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT` to the external libraries that you want to be linked to your plug-in. It might also be necessary to adapt the flags passed to the linker with `PLUGIN_LINK_BFLAGS` and `PLUGIN_LINK_OFLAGS`, but this is heavily dependent on `ocamlyices` itself. More information on the variables that can be used to customize the compilation of your plug-in can be found in section 5.3.3 of [Frama-C's development guide](http://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-plugin-development-guide.pdf).

Comment: I tried to add the 'PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE' and 'PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT' with only ocamlyices.cma and ocamlyices.cmxa respectively and it didn't work... then I added the full path to the files and it worked.

Thank you both for your help.

Comment: @nleitao : could you share how exactly you Makefile looks now? (or what other modifications you had to do). I am stuck with the same problem (and adding PLUGIN_EXTRA_BYTE and PLUGIN_EXTRA_OPT didn't solve it)